# Ubuntu 23.10 Missing Packages libgl1-mesa and libgl1-mesa-glx when installing Zoom

Tags: software-installation, zoom-meeting, 23.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10, and I'm running into a dependency issue when re-installing Zoom. The packages `libgl1-mesa` and `libgl1-mesa-glx` don't seem to exist in any of the 23.10 repositories.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You may download & install the packages from 22.04 repository:

[https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libegl1-mesa_23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libegl1-mesa_23.0.4-0ubuntu1%7E22.04.1_amd64.deb)

[https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgl1-mesa-glx_23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgl1-mesa-glx_23.0.4-0ubuntu1%7E22.04.1_amd64.deb)

And, there's a step by step [tutorial](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/10/install-zoom-ubuntu-2310/) talking about the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Zoom version 5.16.6 (382) fixed this issue. I just installed it without an issue after an Ubuntu upgrade.

I cannot find an explicit mention to this in the [release notes](https://support.zoom.com/hc/en/article?id=zm_kb&sysparm_article=KB0068973), possibly because it's included in the *Minor bug fixes*.

However, the details of the downloadable Debian package indicate that the incriminated dependencies `libgl1-mesa` and `libgl1-mesa-glx` are now listed as recommended instead of dependencies, as you can see below:

```
$ dpkg -I zoom_amd64_5.16.6.deb 
 new Debian package, version 2.0.
 size 186406370 bytes: control archive=34788 bytes.
    1328 bytes,    18 lines      control
  122231 bytes,  1401 lines      md5sums
     593 bytes,    18 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/bash
     226 bytes,    11 lines   *  postrm               #!/bin/bash
 Package: zoom
 Version: 5.16.6.382
 License: see https://www.zoom.us/
 Vendor: Zoom Video Communications, Inc.
 Architecture: amd64
 Maintainer: Zoom Linux Team <https://support.zoom.us>
 Installed-Size: 657201
 Depends: libglib2.0-0, libxcb-keysyms1, libxcb-xinerama0, libdbus-1-3, libxcb-shape0, libxcb-shm0, libxcb-xfixes0, libxcb-randr0, libxcb-image0, libfontconfig1, libxi6, libsm6, libxrender1, libpulse0, libxcomposite1, libxslt1.1, libsqlite3-0, libxcb-xtest0, libxtst6, ibus, libxkbcommon-x11-0, desktop-file-utils, libgbm1, libdrm2, libxcb-cursor0, libxcb-icccm4, libfreetype6 (>= 2.6), libgbm1 (>= 17.1.0~rc2)
 Recommends: libegl1-mesa, libgl1-mesa-glx
 Section: default
 Priority: optional
 Homepage: https://www.zoom.us
 Description: Zoom Cloud Meetings 
  Zoom brings people together to connect and get more done in a frictionless, secure video environment. Our easy, reliable, and innovative video-first solutions provide video meetings and chat, with additional options for webinars and phone service. 
  .
  Zoom is the leading unified communications platform and helps individuals, schools, healthcare professionals and enterprises stay connected. Visit blog.zoom.us and follow @zoom_us. 
  .
  By installing this app, you agree to our Terms of Service (https://zoom.us/terms) and Privacy Statement (https://zoom.us/privacy).
```

Comment: I added some details, hope it's OK :-)

Comment: Excellent! Looks great! You got my upvote! :D